# tf-idf for large number of documents (>100k)

Tags: python, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

So I'm doing tf-idf for very large corpus(100k documents) and it is giving me memory errors. Is there any implantation that can work well with such large number of documents? I want to make my own stopwords list. Also, it worked on 50k documents, what is the limit of number of documents I can use in this calculation if there is one (sklearn implantation).

```
  def tf_idf(self, df):
    df_clean, corpus = self.CleanText(df)
    tfidf=TfidfVectorizer().fit(corpus)
    count_tokens=tfidf.get_feature_names_out()
    article_vect = tfidf.transform(corpus)
    tf_idf_DF=pd.DataFrame(data=article_vect.toarray(),columns=count_tokens)
    tf_idf_DF = pd.DataFrame(tf_idf_DF.sum(axis=0).sort_values(ascending=False))

    return tf_idf_DF
```

The error: MemoryError: Unable to allocate 65.3 GiB for an array with shape (96671, 90622) and data type float64

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line do you get this on?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25145552/tfidf-for-large-dataset

Comment: The limit isn't based on the number of documents.  It's based on memory.  Did you see that in the message?  It's trying to allocate a 65GB array, and that's more memory than your system can allocate, even with a page file.  You will have to use a smaller corpus.

Comment: @TimRoberts The problem is in the memory which can be avoided by reducing the number of documents. The link provided by NickODell shows other implementations such as Gensim's implementation to solve this problem. The other question is also talking about 8 million documents and it worked for them.

Comment: @FjkgB If it's only failing when tfidf is converting into a dataframe, it's likely a conversion from sparse array to dense array that's taking most of the memory.

Comment: @NickODell makes sense, noted. Thank you for all your valuable answers and time!

Answer (score 1):

TfidfVectorizer has a lot of parameters([TfidfVectorizer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)), you should set `max_df=0.9`, `min_df=0.1` and `max_features=500` and gridsearch these parameters for best solution.

Without setting these parameters, you've got a huge sparsematrix with shape of  (96671, 90622) that causing memory error..

welcome to nlp